# Start plotting series starting from certain timestamp in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to start plotting a series ( i.e. ema(close,some_period) ) from a certain timestamp?
I know there is 'show_last' argument inside plot() but I don't know how to calculate how many bars from my timestamp to now for show_last is in integer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will start to plot an EMA from a specific date/time

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

tz = 0 //timezone
timeadj = time + tz * 60 * 60 * 1000 //adjust the time (unix)
t1 = timeadj >= timestamp(2021, 04, 19, 0, 0) ? 1 : 0 //get the starting time

ema = ema(close, 50)
ema_1 = t1 ? ema :na //start ema from the timestamp
plot(ema_1)

barss = barssince(t1 != t1[1]) //get the bars since timestamp
// plot(barss)
```

Comment: I added a line to get the bars since timestamp